rust program cannot find .so library on the path where it is
I am using rustgpu to compile shaders at runtime, meaning I have linked directly against spir-builder rather than using it in a build.rs.
I am getting this error:
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Zcodegen-backend=./librustc_codegen_spirv.so -Zbinary-dep-depinfo -Csymbol-mangling-version=v0 '-Zcrate-attr=feature(register_tool)' '-Zcrate-attr=register_tool(rust_gpu)' -Coverflow-checks=off -Cdebug-assertions=off -Zinline-mir=off '-Cllvm-args=--module-output=multiple --spirv-metadata=name-variables --scalar-block-layout --preserve-bindings target-feature=+RuntimeDescriptorArray,' '-Ctarget-feature=+SampledImageArrayDynamicIndexing,+RuntimeDescriptorArray,+ext:SPV_EXT_descriptor_indexing' --target spirv-unknown-vulkan1.2 --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=split-debuginfo --print=crate-name --print=cfg` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  error: couldn't load codegen backend "./librustc_codegen_spirv.so": ./librustc_codegen_spirv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However, when I do "ls" I do see librustc_codegen_spirv.so under the current path. Moreover, if I set a breakpoint with lldb and run my executable. When I print the current path through platform shell pwd I get the path to the root of my project, as expected.
So how can the binary not find the so library when it is in the path it is looking for?

How do you run that? I think cargo run/cargo build execute in the directory where the Cargo.toml is located, not where you invoke it.

Note that you will get the same error if the library itself is found, but one of its dependencies is missing. Try running ldd ./librustc_codegen_spirv.so and check if one of the dependencies is marked "not found".

@Jmb this is exactly the problem. Thank you

Is it possible to link together the so and all its dependents into a single item?

I have the same issue,
    librustc_driver-1e9cd20e98c23600.so => not found
    libstd-cf8535c351e14653.so => not found

